How to test navigation to page in MAUI?
I have a simple navigation service :
public class NavigationService(INavigation navigation) : INavigationService
{
    public INavigation Navigation { get; } = navigation;

    public void NavigateToControlPage()
    {
        var page = new ControlPage();
        Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    }
}

and the test:
[Fact]
public void NavigationToControlPageShouldPushAsyncPage()
{
    // Arrange
    var navigationMock = new Mock<INavigation>();
    var sut = new Ns.NavigationService(navigationMock.Object);

    // Act
    sut.NavigateToControlPage();

    // Assert
    navigationMock.Verify(n => n.PushAsync(It.IsAny<ControlPage>()), Times.Once);
}

And this test fails because there is exception:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException : Position 9:11. StaticResource not found for key Grey1
I think the test tries to create/open ControlPage and the static resource doesn't exist. I am wondering if my way of doing navigation via service is good? Also, is my test good? General question: how can I test my service? I want to test that method to Navigation my ControlPage.
Edit. Maybe I should attach someway static resource directory in test project?
